GnuCOBOL and MySQL C API interface problem (called function not found)
C:\gnuCobol>cobc -d -v -x -o mysql1 mysql1.cob -L"C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\lib" -llibmysql
cobc (GnuCOBOL) 3.2.0
Built     Jul 28 2023 16:08:08  Packaged  Jul 28 2023 16:58:47 UTC
C version (MinGW) "13.1.0"
loading standard configuration file 'default.conf'
command line:   cobc -d -v -x -o mysql1 -LC:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\lib -llibmysql mysql1.cob 
preprocessing:  mysql1.cob -> C:\Users\Omistaja\AppData\Local\Temp\cob83652_0.cob
return status:  0
parsing:        C:\Users\Omistaja\AppData\Local\Temp\cob83652_0.cob (mysql1.cob)
return status:  0
translating:    C:\Users\Omistaja\AppData\Local\Temp\cob83652_0.cob -> C:\Users\Omistaja\AppData\Local\Temp\cob83652_0.c (mysql1.cob)
executing:      gcc -c -I"C:\gnuCobol\include" -o
                "C:\Users\Omistaja\AppData\Local\Temp\cob83652_0.o"
                "C:\Users\Omistaja\AppData\Local\Temp\cob83652_0.c"
return status:  0
executing:      gcc -Wl,--export-all-symbols -Wl,--enable-auto-import
                -Wl,--enable-auto-image-base -o "mysql1.exe"
                "C:\Users\Omistaja\AppData\Local\Temp\cob83652_0.o"
                -L"C:\gnuCobol\lib" -L"C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server
                8.0\lib" -L/mingw64/lib -lcob -l"libmysql"
return status:  0

C:\gnuCobol>mysql1
libcob: mysql1.cob:17: error: module 'mysql_init' not found

 Last statement of "MySQL1" was CALL at line 17 of mysql1.cob
        ENTRY MySQL1 at mysql1.cob:17
 Started by mysql1

C:\gnuCobol>
--
 PROCEDURE DIVISION.
      * Step 1: Open the MySQL connection
           CALL "mysql_init" USING DB-CONNECTION-HANDLE
           END-CALL
           IF DB-CONNECTION-HANDLE = 0
               DISPLAY "Failed to initialize MySQL connection."
               STOP RUN
           END-IF

Anybody know what the problem is?

Read this and edit your question afterwards. Welcome to StackOverflow

-llibmysql is not usual in C speak (you're using cobc: I assume its arguments follow the same rules as gcc). We use -lmysql to link with the "libmysql" library

-lmysql not works ok

option 1:  C:\gnuCobol>mysql1
libcob: warning: preloading of 'libmysql' failed
libcob: mysql1.cob:22: error: module 'mysql_init' not found
Last statement of "MySQL1" was CALL at line 22 of mysql1.cob
ENTRY MySQL1 at mysql1.cob:21
Started by mysql1

for option 1: is the dll named libmysql.dll ? Is it in one of the COB_LIBRARY_PATH elements?

option 1: COB_LIBRARY_PATH=C:\gnuCobol\extras;C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\lib
COB_MAIN_DIR=C:\gnuCobol
COB_PRE_LOAD=libmysql         (=libmysql.dll)

This cobc uses gcc (and ld) for compile/link, so this is what currently happens:
Your program does a dynamic CALL (that's the default for GnuCOBOL) to a C entry point.
You link a library that includes this entry point.
The linker finds that this entry point is never called, so optimizes this away and also removes the complete library, as there's no single use left.
The COBOL runtime tries to resolve the entry point from all loaded libraries (libmsql is not in there any more - you can verify that for example by analyzing the generated executable with Dependencies), then tries to find it in all preloaded modules (you don't have any), then tries to open a shared object with that name, which does not exist.
Options:

stay with dynamic CALLs, preload the library:
cobc -d -v -x -o mysql1 mysql1.cob (no linking options for mysql any more)
possibly with catching this in the program (if you don't want a hard abort):
CALL "mysql_init" USING DB-CONNECTION-HANDLE ON EXCEPTION CONTINUE.
set COB_PRE_LOAD=libmysql, set COB_LIBRARY_PATH=%COB_LIBRARY_PATH%;C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\lib (if there's a libmysql.dll in there, otherwise adjust), mysql1

change to static CALLs
this needs -L"\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\lib" -lmysql, then adjust the CALL by one of:

CALL STATIC "mysql_init"  (include the call convention "STATIC" for all other entry points in that library)
CALL "mysql_init" and cobc -K mysql_init (include the "-K" for all other entry points)
CALL "mysql_init" and cobc --static (to force a dynamic load, for example for COBOL modules you then need to change those to MOVE "PROG" TO variable. CALL variable.


Leave dynamic CALL and disable the linker optimization with cobc -Q "-Wl,--no-as-needed"


Note 1: Ensure that your called libraries use the same architecture (the MySQL library in that path is likely x64 - not sure if your GnuCOBOL uses the same).
Note 2: If you just start with the SQL parts, I suggest considering to not directly call into the MySQL library but use an SQL preprocessor with the standard EXEC SQL.
While this removes the option for low-level calls, it is quite portable and also allows to change the db target quite easily later (for example to ODBC or PostgreSQL). A very portable option is GixSQL, which also provides Windows binary installers.
